# How do I decrypt cipher text to plaintext

Tags: python, cryptography, des

I want to decrypt the cipher text to plaintext as normal when the user will provide key and cipher_text

Here's my code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES

key = input('Enter your key: ').encode('utf-8')
myDes = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_ECB)
print('Please select option:\n1. Encryption\n2. Decryption\n3. Exit')

while True:
    user_choice = input("Choose a option: ")
    if user_choice == "1":
        plain_text = input("Please enter your text: ")
        modified_plain_text = plain_text.encode("utf-8")
        cipher_text = myDes.encrypt(plain_text.encode("utf-8"))
        print(f"Encrypted text: {cipher_text}")

    elif user_choice == "2":
        user_cipher_text = input(
            "Please enter your cipher text: ").encode('utf-8')
        text = myDes.decrypt(user_cipher_text, DES.block_size)

    elif user_choice == "3":
        print("Quitting The Program....")
        break
    else:
        print("Please Choose a correct option")
```

But when I run it I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manish\Downloads\DES.py", line 17, in <module>
    text = myDes.decrypt(user_cipher_text,DES.block_size)
  File "C:\python38\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_ecb.py", line 183, in decrypt
    raise TypeError("output must be a bytearray or a writeable memoryview")
TypeError: output must be a bytearray or a writeable memoryview
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your program to produce the ciphertext output with hexadecimal encoding, and accept the ciphertext input with hexadecimal encoding.  That way, you can print the ciphertext as regular text instead of a byte array, and the user can enter the ciphertext as a regular string (instead of a byte array) using the keyboard.  (You could use a different encoding method, such as base64 instead of hexadecimal).  I also cleaned up a few other things as well:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES
import binascii

key = input('Enter your key: ').encode('utf-8')
myDes = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_ECB)
print('Please select option:\n1. Encryption\n2. Decryption\n3. Exit')

while True:
    user_choice = input("Choose a option: ")
    if user_choice == "1":
        plain_text = input("Please enter your text: ")
        cipher_text = myDes.encrypt(plain_text.encode("utf-8"))
        print("Encrypted text:", cipher_text.hex())

    elif user_choice == "2":
        user_cipher_text = input("Please enter your cipher text: ")
        text = myDes.decrypt(binascii.unhexlify(user_cipher_text))
        print("Decrypted text:", text.decode('utf-8'))

    elif user_choice == "3":
        print("Quitting The Program....")
        break
    else:
        print("Please Choose a correct option")
```

Note that the keys and the inputs must be multiples of 8 bytes.  If so, then this functions as expected:

```
$ python3 sajjan.py 
Enter your key: asdfghjk
Please select option:
1. Encryption
2. Decryption
3. Exit
Choose a option: 1
Please enter your text: testtest
Encrypted text: 3049caf9d8c9b7cb
Choose a option: 3
Quitting The Program....
$ python3 sajjan.py 
Enter your key: asdfghjk
Please select option:
1. Encryption
2. Decryption
3. Exit
Choose a option: 2
Please enter your cipher text: 3049caf9d8c9b7cb
Decrypted text: testtest
Choose a option: 3
Quitting The Program....
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `decrypt` is not a length (of anything). It is an optional argument that, if supplied, will cause decrypt to try to place the output there. Thus, that parameter must be a `bytearray` or a `memoryview` that is writeable.

Just get rid of the last parameter and make it

```
text = myDes.decrypt(user_cipher_text)
```